# Show/hide a link based on checkbox value and saved session

Tags: html, django, checkbox, show-hide, django-sessions

I don't know how to accomplish this. I have this checkbox that when check will show the link and once unchecked will hide the link.

```js
$('#chk').click(function(){
  if( $(this).is(':checked') )
  {
    $('#link1').show();
  }
  else
  {
    $('#link1').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="chk" />Check
<ul>
 <li id="link1">Link 1</li>
</ul>
```

It should be like this, if I leave the checkbox checked(link should be shown) then I logout, once I login again the link should be shown and vice versa. What should I do to save it to session? Do I need to get the value of the checkbox then saved it in session? Hope someone could help. Thanks. I'm just a newbie in django.

Comment: local storage may help

Comment: I can answer this in JS. will that be ok?

Comment: May I see? I really don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance @SankarshMakam

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
$('#chk').change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
       $('#link1').show();
    }else{
       $('#link1').hide();
    }
});
```